# Unable to find the wrapper

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

В чем ошибка?

> `file_get_contents() [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: Unable to find the wrapper &quot;https&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?`

Comment: >>did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Это проверяли? Как скомпилирован PHP?

[Вопрос на StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config)

Это найдено поиском - не пытались попробовать?

У меня когда была такая проблема - обнаружил лишний пробел, т.е. было " https:/..."

Comment: поиск пробовала, не беспокойтесь=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать curl.
С

```
file_get_contents('https://....')
```

постоянно куча проблем

Так же еще вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7499529) почитай

Answer (score 1):

Обращение к http идет как-то неправильно, напиши код где используется `file_get_contents()`

Comment: `https`, а не `http`

Comment: $link="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kz.crystalspring.pit_stop_kz";
   
$html = file_get_html($link);

Comment: А причем здесь ** $html = file_get_html($link); **если в вопросе про **file_get_contents**